# IHttpModule not being applied to virtual directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-6, ihttpmodule

I have a network folder that is mapped to my iis app as a virtual directory and I'm trying to do some authentication for files that are located there with an ihttpmodule.  I've verified that the ihttpmodule is firing properly for anything else in my app, just not the files located in virtual directory.  Most of what I've found is that the directory can't be listed as an application (which it isn't), and everything should work.  The other solution that I found was to add the the module tag to the  tag, but that didn't seem to help either.  Everything that I've found talks about stopping this from happening.  So my question is what could be set that is causing this to not work?  Is there a certain execute permission that needs to be set?  Any other iis settings that could cause this?  It is an mvc app, and this is how my directory structure is laid out:

server/app  <- my application folder

server/app/content/downloads <- downloads is the virtual directory

Do I have to add the virtual directory directly under my app directory?  Is that part of the problem?  I don't have direct control of the server my code is running on, so testing things out is a bit of a pain...  so I was looking for some more thoughts before starting to send emails off to my operations people.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I found what the issue is....  it looks like by default, iis6 does not pass executables, zip files, or anything of that nature through the .net runtime.  It only does that with .aspx files and such, so it will never fire my ihttpmodule.  It looks like you can force it to by adding a mapping for that extension, but is there a code work around for this?  Or is that the only way?

Comment: Ok, so I was able to add a wildcard mapping in iis, and that seemed to take care of it!